# Copying a file using 2 disks with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ftp

I have 2 disks in Laravel.

One is the local disk, the other one is a FTP server which I need to upload my files to. They are both correctly configured.

I have attempted it this way:

```
 Storage::disk('FTP')->copy('old/file1.jpg', 'new/file1.jpg');
```

This would only copy the file if it is already in the FTP server. I have also read the documentation and there seems to be no way to combine both in order to upload files.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A simple combination of `Storage::get` and `Storage::put` should do the trick.

```
Storage::disk('FTP')->put('new/file1.jpg', Storage::get('old/file1.jpg'));
```

Comment: Will this stream the copy or do it in one big go?

Comment: @JonMcClung This would be two separate steps - the server will have to fully download the file before reuploading it to the other spot.

Answer (score 73):

@ceejayoz has a good answer, but as mentioned in the comments, this fetches, and then writes.

In order to use streams, the following can be used instead:

```
Storage::disk('FTP')->writeStream('new/file1.jpg', Storage::readStream('old/file1.jpg'));
```

Comment: Just a note that if there is already a file at that location it throws a FileExistsException